# How do I group an array by a key, but accumulate unique property values into a list

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects of type `User[]`:

```
type User = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   role: string;
};
```

It is possible that there are multiple users in this array with the same `id` but different `role` (e.g. admin or editor). I need to transform the above array into an array of objects of type:

```
type GroupedUser = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   roles: string[];
};
```

where for any user with the same id, their roles are aggregated into an array of roles.

Comment: loop the user array, then add it into one dictionary (key: id, value: user) like `dict[user.id].roles.push(user.role)`, finally, get the result by `Object.values(dict)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array#reduce`, which transforms an array into another value entirely, to achieve this:

```js
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  role: string;
}

interface GroupedUser extends Omit<User, "role"> {
  roles: Array<User["role"]>;
}

const users: Array<User> = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "User 1",
    role: "editor",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "User 1",
    role: "admin",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "User 2",
    role: "editor",
  },
];

const grouped = users.reduce<Array<GroupedUser>>(
  (groupedUsers, currentUser) => {
    const matchingGroupedUserIndex = groupedUsers.findIndex(
      (g) => g.id === currentUser.id
    );

    if (matchingGroupedUserIndex === -1) { // If we haven't encountered this user yet, add them to the array!
      groupedUsers.push({
        id: currentUser.id,
        name: currentUser.name,
        roles: [currentUser.role],
      });
    } else { // Otherwise, append their role!
      groupedUsers[matchingGroupedUserIndex].roles.push(currentUser.role);
    }

    return groupedUsers;
  },
  []
);
```

`grouped` will then be the following:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "User 1",
    "roles": [
      "editor",
      "admin"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "User 2",
    "roles": [
      "editor"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Using a Map or object as the accumulator would be a lot more efficient

Comment: I agree but OP said they needed an array.

Comment: Fine... you can still return an array. Object.values(grouped) for example  or spread a Map's values